# Swap keys in nested map in Elixir

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, elixir

I have nested map with following structure in Elixir:

```
%{
  key1: %{
    nkey1: val1,
    nkey2: val4
  },
  key2: %{
    nkey1: val2,
    nkey2: val5
  },
  key3: %{
    nkey1: val3,
    nkey2: val6
  }
}
```

And I'd like to transform it to the following structure.

```
%{
  nkey1: %{
    key1: val1,
    key2: val2,
    key3: val3
  },
  nkey2: %{
    key1: val4,
    key2: val5,
    key3: val6
}
```

It is **guaranteed** that all the top-level keys contain the same set of nested keys.

What is some nice, simple way to do this transformation, I am able to achieve it somehow, but it doesn't strike me as really *beautiful*.

Comment: You've asked a subjective question here about what is "beautiful".  Can you share the code you've come up with for comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like comprehensions for traversing nested data, myself.

```rb
for {key, nested} <- input, {nkey, value} <- nested, reduce: %{} do
  acc ->
    put_in(acc, [Access.key(nkey, %{}), key], value)
    # The Access functions are less-known, so you may prefer this for understandability:
    # Map.update(acc, nkey, %{key => value}, &Map.put(&1, key, value))
end
```

Comment: This is certainly a way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I frankly doubt there could be a super-elegant solution. I would go with nested `Enum.reduce/3`.

```rb
map = %{
  key1: %{nkey1: 1, nkey2: 4},
  key2: %{nkey1: 2, nkey2: 5},
  key3: %{nkey1: 3, nkey2: 6}
}

Enum.reduce(map, %{}, fn {k, v}, acc ->
  Enum.reduce(v, acc, fn {kk, vv}, acc ->
    Map.update(acc, kk, %{k => vv}, &Map.put(&1, k, vv))
  end)
end)
#⇒ %{nkey1: %{key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3},
#    nkey2: %{key1: 4, key2: 5, key3: 6}}
```

Comment: That's quite elegant, using the ```Map.update```!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Aleksei's answer, I did it like this:

```
map
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {key, val}, acc ->
  Map.merge(acc, val |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {nkey, nval}, nacc ->
    Map.put(nacc, nkey, Map.new([{key, nval}]))
  end),
  fn _dkey, dval1, dval2 -> Map.merge(dval1, dval2) end)
end)
```

I think Aleksei's answer is more elegant and possibly more efficient.

Comment: `Map.new([{key, nval}])` → `%{key => nval}`.